# Ftp folder list recovery slow after changing internet provider

Tags: performance, ftp

I've tried a few FTP servers connection and with different software, and they all have the same problem. The connection with the FTP server happens very quickly, but when I ask for the list of files contained in a folder it takes 15 seconds. And even the start of uploading a file takes a long time. With FileZilla if I upload 10 files under 10KB, each file takes 9 seconds ! While a 210Mb file was uploaded in about 2 and a half minutes, more or less the correct time for the upload speed of the line.

It didn't happen with the old internet provider, and trying with another line it doesn't happen, but instead the same thing happens in our second office where we updated the internet with the same internet provider.

What is the problem, and what solution can I adopt (or what can I ask the new internet provider) for the slowness I'm experiencing?

Thanks